# C++ std::vector<T*> if you hold a pointer to a pointer element, does it become invalidated upon resize?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, vector, data-structures

Let us say I create `std::vector<int*> myVec;` and reserve 100 entries and populate the vector with values so that all 100 elements have valid pointers. I then cache a pointer to one of the elements,

```
int * x = myVec[60];
```

Then, if I append another `int *` which triggers a resize along with a move due to heap fragmentation, does the previous pointer to a pointer become invalidated or does it point to the new location in memory?

If my memory servers me correct, if the example were to `std::vector<int> myVecTwo` with the same conditions as above and I stored a ptr like

```
int * x = &myVecTwo[60];
```

and proceeded to append and resize, that pointer would be invalided.

So, my question is as follows. Would the pointer to the pointer become invalidated? I am no longer certain because of the new C++ std functionality of [is_trivially_copyable](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/is_trivially_copyable/) and whether the std::vector makes use of such functionality or POD checks.

Would the pointer by invalidated in C++11?

Comment: It's quite simple.  If you have an iterator, or a reference/pointer to an element of your vector, that will be invalidated after resize (_i.e._ you must assume it's no longer valid).  In your first example, this is not the case.  You are simply copying a pointer already stored in the vector -- you are not storing a pointer to the actual vector's storage for that value.  That's fine: `x` will be the same pointer after a resize.  In your second example, yes absolutely `x` may not be valid after resizing.  Regarding pointer-to-pointer, I don't see any of these in your question.

Comment: your terminology is strange, there is no "pointer to a pointer" in your samples, your first sample is just copying a pointer

Comment: What I am asking is if I am copying a pointer to an element in the vector and because of a resize, each pointer is deleted and having new called on it, does that pointer I originally copied point to the same value in memory. Sorry for the confusion. Are you sure it isn't invalidated?

Comment: @kmdreko the int * x is pointing to the pointer element in the vector at index 60. If its copying a pointer, as you suggested, and that pointer is changed through a resize, wouldn't it then point to something else? That is what I am asking

Comment: no its not, that'd be a `int**`, `int * x` is pointing to what `myVec[60]` points to, after the assignment there is no association to `myVec` whatsoever

Comment: Got it, sorry for the mistake in wording @kmdreko

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

As you showed, after the reallocation, the pointers to the elements of the `vector`, like `int * x = &myVecTwo[60];` would be invalidated. After the reallocation, the elements themselves would be copied, but the object pointed by the element pointers won't be affected, then for `int * x = myVec[60];`, after the reallocation `x` is still pointing to the same object, which has nothing to do with the reallocation of the `vector`.